# jQuery - replace all instances of a character in a string

Tags: jquery, string, replace

This does not work and I need it badly

```
$('some+multi+word+string').replace('+', ' ' );
```

always gets

```
some multi+word+string
```

it's always replacing for the first instance only, but I need it to work for all + symbols.

Comment: The biggest question I have, right now, is why are you making a jQuery object from a string, instead of `"some+multi+word+string".replace(/\+/g,' ');`? Oh, and take a read of [Mozilla Developer Network's 'Regular Expressions'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) page. It's helpful, and explains things pretty well.

Comment: actually it's a variable that turns into a string

Comment: But if the variable has the value of a string, or a string is assigned to that variable, just call `replace()` on the variable: `var str = 'some+multi+word+string'; str.replace(/\+/g,' ');`

Comment: @DavidThomas: That won't do anything at all. You have to use the result from the `replace` method, it doesn't change the string that it's called on. E.g. `str = str.replace(/\+/g, ' ');`

Comment: @Guffa: I know, for reasons that made sense at the time, I opted to leave out the assignation to another variable. I think I was just trying to show how to use `replace()` on a variable. And, apparently, leaving out the essential part about doing something useful... =/

Comment: I vote for regular expression solution

Comment: A modern solution to this problem would be `str.replaceAll()`. You can use it like `'some+multi+word+string'.replaceAll('+', ' ' );`

Answer (score 435, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression, so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
var s = 'some+multi+word+string'.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
```

(I removed the `$()` around the string, as `replace` is not a jQuery method, so that won't work at all.)

Comment: how can I use a variable in this code like this example:  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    str = str.replace(/"_0x69b9[" + i.toString() + "]"/g, _array[i]);
}

Comment: You would create a `RegExp` object from a string:  `str = str.replace(new RegExp('"_0x69b9[' + i + ']"', 'g'), _array[i]);`. However, consider if you instead can use `(\d+)` in the pattern to match any number and catch it for lookup in a replacement function, that way you could replace all instances in one replacement instead of doing 101 replacements.

Comment: In case you can't get it to work, it's easy to overlook that /\+/g is not inside quotes.  It took a bit of head scratching before I realised that.

Comment: can we pass a variable instead of fixed string?

Comment: It works with characters but how can we remove multiple blank spaces from a string eg. '999 999 9999'.replace(/\ /g, ' '); does not work. kindly share any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

```
'some+multi+word+string'.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
                                   ^^^^^^
```

'g' = "global"

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it needs to be regex, and yes the `g` switch is required. But, no: [`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eD23g/).

Comment: @DavidThomas I've been thinking about this for 4 years, and I disagree.  Or rather, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: it's haunted madbreaks deeply. Sleep has not come easy the last 4 years whilst @Madbreaks mind is going crazy with ideas on how it doesn't work - on another note ^+1 - thanks for explaining the g in the replace() function

Comment: Downvoter, please explain

Comment: @Madbreaks David posted that before you edited your answer. Before it used the Jquery syntax. "$(string).replace..". This will result in an error. You can check the history of your answer and also click the link of the error David had shown.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder @KerwinSneijders

Answer (score 10):

RegEx is the way to go in most cases.

In some cases, it may be faster to specify more elements or the specific element to perform the replace on:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myclass').each(function () {
        $('img').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_s.jpg', '_n.jpg'));
        })
    })
});
```

This does the replace once on each string, but it does it using a more specific selector.