# Encoding + character

Tags: jquery, json, encoding, special-characters

I am using $.Ajax to call a web method and passing few parameters which are received in webmethod and used for server request. However, one of the param value may have special charaters including +. I could do away with all others by using encoding but seems + is not getting encoded. Encoded value for space ' ' is + so may be it is considered already encoded and skiped. Moreover, while decoding, that + is considered as space and shown as space in final text value. I need to persist +. How can I do it?

Comment: How are you encoding it?

Comment: Using javascript function encodeURIComponent()

Comment: encodeURIComponent(' ') is %20 while encodeURIComponent('+') should be %2B. Using encodeURIComponent() should be fine. I think your problem is from other place.

Comment: The problem was myParam can contain a text value as "This is sample text containing + character". From this, + was not getting encoded. Thanks Brian! Your comment and link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574980/jquery-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string shown me the path. Now I am doing encodeURIComponent(myParam.replace(/\+/g, '\%2B')) and it is working fine!