# Wrap every asterix in a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Can anyone share how I could wrap every asterix on a page within an enclosing div.

So that:

```html
Tasty drinks *
```

Becomes:

```html
Tasty drinks <span class="disclaimer">*</span>
```

I've tried a few online examples and can get it to work on almost any character except an asterix.

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: In case you use a regular expression, be aware that `*` is a special character and needs to be escaped, so it becomes `\*`.

Comment: `replace \* with <span class="disclaimer">\*</span>` ?  thanks to @simone pointing out to escape the special char

Answer (score 6):

If you are using jQuery, you could use

```
$("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\*/g,"<span class='disclaimer'>*</span>"));
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandonhorst/jp96C/92/)
(Adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643766/find-and-replace-specific-text-characters-across-a-document-with-js))

Comment: Thanks Brandon. That worked beautifully. I'll try to tweak so it's not dependent on the click.

Comment: Please take a second and mark it as the answer if you get the chance, for future viewers. Thank you!