# Why is replace() disrupting onclick()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using replace to search my dynamically loaded webpage for this symbol Æ and replace it with ®. I found the code to do so in this question:
[Find and replace specific text characters across a document with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643766/find-and-replace-specific-text-characters-across-a-document-with-js/18643955#18643955)

```
    $("body").children().each(function () {
            $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Æ/g,"&reg;") );
    });
```

However, after I added this code, this function stopped working.

```
    document.getElementById("backToClasses").onclick = function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    };
```

Can anyone tell me why this might happen?

Comment: You are replacing the entirety of the html content of `body`. You'll need to reassign all event handlers previously in place as the entire DOM is regenerated with your replace method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second chunk of code (which I assume runs first) you are locating an element in the DOM and assigning a value to a property of it.

The first chunk of code goes over the DOM and converts large chunks of it into HTML source code, it then modifies that source code, then it generates **new** DOM elements from it and replaces whatever was there before with them.

So the element with the ID `backToClasses`:

1. Gets a click handler
2. Is converted to HTML
3. Is **destroyed**
4. Is replaced by a new version created from its old HTML

The click handler was only ever on the DOM, so the new element doesn't have it.

---

If you are going to take this approach, then you should look at looping over just the *text nodes* in the document and dealing in text rather than HTML. To do that you'll need to recursively loop over the DOM and test the node type of each element.

It would be better to fix the underlying problem that you are hacking around though. It is almost certainly down to an incorrectly specified character encoding somewhere.

The W3C has some [material on character encodings](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/) that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this!  I spent a little time doing more research on how replace() works, and instead of trying to search everything in one fell swoop, I used a bunch of smaller searches. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/Æ/g,"&reg;") );
});
```

You re-create all the `HTML` elements, so any events that you might have bound before are lost. Don't use the `.html()` function to replace text. And still, I'm not sure that this is the best way to replace a character.

This replace should be done **server-side**, not client side. By doing it client-side (in JavaScript) you can get into different problems like SEO (Google indexing your site with your badly encoded characters). If the characters are like this inside a file, simply replace them in that file, make sure to save the file with the right encoding.

Comment: Using `text()` will destroy the HTML elements too, it just won't create new ones, so all the paragraphs, links, and so will be lost.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said I was not sure it will work.