# How can I remove text in <li> and after <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove `"Text"` in an `<li>`.

Here's my attempt:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var str = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[0].innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replace("Text", "Hello");
  document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[0].innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

It does not work because `"data-rel"` has the same value as the text that I want to remove.

I can't change or remove the value in `"data-rel"`.

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText) may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace specific text characters across a document with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643766/find-and-replace-specific-text-characters-across-a-document-with-js) - In particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50835546/1871033) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) to set the text content of your nodes without disrupting other child elements.

```js
const node = document.querySelector("li.slide-2").childNodes[1];
node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/Text/g, "Hello");

const dataset = document.querySelector("div.slide-2").dataset;
console.log("is the `data-rel` attribute still `Text`?", dataset);
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you want to replace multiple occurrences:

```js
for (const node of [...document.querySelectorAll("li.slide-2")]) {
  const child = node.childNodes[node.childNodes.length-1];
  child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(/Text/g, "Hello");
}
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2">
      <div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2">
        this Text won't be touched... 
      </div>
      Text and some more Text text.
    </li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2">
      <div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2">
        this Text also won't be touched... 
      </div>
      Text
    </li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

Consider using `/\bText\b/g` if you want to enforce word boundaries and disregard `Textual`.

Applying the `slide-2` class name to both the child `<div>` and parent `<li>` may be a potential antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[0].innerHTML; 
      var res = str.replace(/Text/gi, "Hello");
      document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[0].innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the childNodes, loop over and find text node (3) with the text you want to match.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2");
  Array.from(lis).forEach(function(li) {
    var textNode = Array.from(li.childNodes).find(function(node) {
      // return node.nodeType == 3;
      return node.nodeType == 3 && node.nodeValue === "Text";
    })
    // if (textNode) textNode.nodeValue = "";
    if (textNode) textNode.remove();
  })
}
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
  <li class="slide-1">001</li>
  <li class="slide-2">
    <div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
  <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
  <li class="slide-1">001</li>
  <li class="slide-2">
    <div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div>Text</li>
  <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just add a new div with the same class name after image, but hey its working XD

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var count = document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2").length; 
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    if(document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[i].innerHTML == "Text"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("slide-2")[i].innerHTML = "Hello";  
    }
  } 
}
```

```html
<ul class="box1">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div><div class="slide-2">Text</div></li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>

<ul class="box2">
    <li class="slide-1">001</li>
    <li class="slide-2"><div data-rel="Text" class="slide-2"><img src=".."></div><div class="slide-2">Text</div></li>
    <li class="slide-3">003</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

what about splitting

```
str = str.split('</div>');
str[1] = 'Hello';
let res = str.join('</div>');
```