# Get the text after element

Tags: jquery, html

I have code

```
<div>
    <a href="#"></a> »
    <a href="#"></a> »
    <a href="#"></a> »
    <a href="#"></a> »
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

How i can disable or delete this simbol - "»" ?

I use this code

```
text = $('div').html();
text = text.replace('»','');
$('div').html(text);
```

but hi does not wokr correctly. The last symbol is displaing.

Another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574980/jquery-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the global flag (`g`) to your replace code like it was a regex:

```
text = $('div').html();
text = text.replace(/»/g,'');
$('div').html(text);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ma2z6jcL/)**

Answer (score 2):

`replace` when passed a string only replaces the first instance. You must use a regular expression instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/zkvss6uf/

```
text = $('div').html();
text = text.replace(/»/g,'');
$('div').html(text);
```