# How can I put <br> tag in <td> contents with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, replace, replaceall

In my `<td>` tag, there are few `-.` in it. What I want to do is, put `<br>` tag in front of this specific word. I did `replace()` function but it changed just one `-.` How do I find all instances of `-.`?

#### Original Text

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. -.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. -.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.

#### What I want

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**-.** Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.

**-.** It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.

#### This is my Code example

```
<table class="Notice">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. -.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. -.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('td:contains("-.")').html(function (i, htm) {
    return htm.replace(/-./g, "<br>-.");
});
```

#### Solution

I found my mistake - I didn't do 'every' word. So I used the `each()` function, and it works perfectly!

```
$('td:contains("-.")').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/-./g, "<br>-."));
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13574989/1107638

Comment: You want to replace or you want to add in front of that??

Comment: Can you provide your javascript code where you used replace(). May be there is a mistake threre? Actually it should work as you expect. See for an examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: @candle I add! :) This way works just one `-.` part.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao add in front of this! I used 'replace' method because I thought it change html and do <br> tag.

Comment: Try the replaceAll function from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137436/useful-javascript-methods-that-extends-built-in-objects/1137579#1137579

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function with global matching.

```
replace(/-/g,"<br />-");
```

Comment: Thanks :) But that function was just for one `-.` . Finally I solved myself with each() function. `$('td:contains("-.")').each(function () { $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/-./g, "<br>-.")); });` this works!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button</p>

<p id="demo">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. -.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. -.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    text = text.replace(new RegExp("-.","g"), "<br>-.");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text ;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks your help,@candle :) I can adjust this when I using button.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```html
<p id="changeMe"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. -.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. -.It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting.</p>
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script>
 
 var p = document.getElementById("changeMe");
 p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/-./g, "<br>-. ");
 </script>
```