# Find all instances in text and replace all

Tags: jquery, html, replace, replaceall

I am trying to create a table and **replace all** instances inside the td not just the first one. In this case replace all the "/" inside the td tag and not just the first one.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
  <table border="1">
      <tr><td class="abc">apple</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="abc">ball</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="abc">cat</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="abc">dog/ss/s</td></tr>
  </table>
```

jQuery

```
   $('.abc').each(function() {
    var xyz = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(xyz.replace('/', 'puppy')); 
});
```

Here is a working example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashmee_p/s35at23t/1/)

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use regex with global `g`

```js
 $('.abc').each(function() {
   var xyz = $(this).text();
   $(this).text(xyz.replace(/\//g, 'puppy'));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there

try this:

```
 $('.abc').each(function() {
    var xyz = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(xyz.replace(/\//g, 'puppy')); 
});
```

You need to use global flag.

Here is the explanation. 
[jQuery - replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574980/jquery-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)