# Highlights a word in paragraph with a jQuery .mouseenter on a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseenter

I've stocked in a var, the text of my tag when i mouseenter, and now i would put the same word if it's in a paragraph document, in highlights like a color or in bold .css()

here is my code, the alert allows me to know which text i put in my var 'leContenu' :

```
    var leContenu;
    $('.chip').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (e.type === 'mouseenter'){
            $(this).siblings(".chip").not(".noselect").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '0.7'}, 'fast');
            //alert ($(this).text());
            leContenu = $(this).text();

            $('p').find(leContenu).css('color', 'red');

    //another try
            /*
            return this.html(function() {
                alert ($(this).text());
                $('p').wrapInner(leContenu).css('color', 'red');
            });
            */
    //end another try

        }
        else{
            $(this).siblings(".chip").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'fast');
        }
    });
```

And the Html is here:

```
        <div class="var-category">
        <p class="title-category">Zone de communication</p>
        <div class="chips">
            <p class="chip">@ville</p>
            <p class="chip">@cp</p>
            <p class="chip">@ville1</p>
            <p class="chip">@ville2</p>
            <p class="chip">@ville3</p>
            <p class="chip noselect">@ville4</p>
            <p class="chip">@loc</p>
            <p class="chip">@dpt</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
            <div class="Tcard">
                <div class="title-page">
                    <h2 class="h2popout">Edition de contenu n°1</h2>
                </div>
                <ul class="collapsible popout collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">subtitles</i>First</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Ce paragraphe présente les prestations client sous forme de liste à puce</p>
                            <a href="#"><strong>Contribution</strong> H2</a>
                            <p>Phrases</p>
                            <p>Liste à puce + liens internes</p>
                            <p>CTA</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p><strong class="tagVar">BML</strong> est une <span class="tagVar">@ville</span> spécialisée dans la fission nucléaire, dans le Rhône : à <span class="tagVar">Lyon</span>.</p>
                            <p>Nous proposons tout plein de jolis champignons à nos clients afin de développer une synergie
                            dans la confection de réseaux créatif. Il est important de noter l'impact écologique de nos centrales
                            en <span class="tagVar">carton</span>. <span class="tagVar">Contactez-nous</span> pour plus d'informations sur le sujet.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I don't understand which function will allow me to search and modify in

Anyone knows?

Comment: please have a look a this https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: yeah but how to make a correspondance between the text i got from a tag in an aside, and  a text in the paragraph?

Comment: $('p:contains(leContenu)').css('color', 'red');
doesn't work, text doesn't change

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do, can you provide me with a html ?

Comment: when i mouseenter on a p .chip, the text inside should reveal the same word in a different section, like a highlight.

Comment: Hmmm, i got an issue when i mouseenter, all tags are in highlight, despite the only one i mouseIn. and the <p> has to blured but not the one in question. I've tried to select .val() but it doesn't work. Could you explain me why please? Here a https://jsfiddle.net/yggcedg8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a code working for this

```js
var leContenu;
var repl;
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#chip", function(e) {
 if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
  if($('#body').find('.myClass').length > 0){
   $('#body').find('.myClass').css("color", "red");
  }else{
   leContenu = $(this).text().trim();
      
   var rgxp = new RegExp("\\b" + leContenu + "\\b" , 'gi');
   repl = '<span class="myClass">' + leContenu + '</span>';
   
   $('#body').html($('#body').html().replace(rgxp, repl));
  }
 }else{
  $('#body').find('.myClass').css('color', "black");
 }
});
```

```css
.myClass{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body">
  <div>
    <div id='chip' class=".chip">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>a
  
<h1>HTML Test Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean test, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem test dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Brent, i've realised that i needed .replace, and you came back with an awesome answer. +1 You rocks, i've used uom-pgregorio's code in order to insert in mine easily, but you've done a big part of the work. have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm late to the party. My solution is similar to @BrentBoden.

#### HTML

```
<div class="chips">
  <p class="chip">@ville</p>
  <p class="chip">@cp</p>
  <p class="chip">@ville1</p>
  <p class="chip">@ville2</p>
  <p class="chip">@ville3</p>
  <p class="chip noselect">@ville4</p>
  <p class="chip">@loc</p>
  <p class="chip">@dpt</p>
</div>
<div class="search">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur @ville adipiscing elit. @ville2 Mauris non justo laoreet, tristique ex non, sodales odio. Sed ac nunc nisl. Mauris eu laoreet ligula, ac condimentum eros. Vivamus risus neque, mattis ac laoreet @cp non, imperdiet eget nunc. Cras porttitor volutpat leo, quis rhoncus nulla. Sed hendrerit sagittis neque, quis iaculis felis elementum eu. Donec et tristique sapien, sed scelerisque est. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas at fringilla @ville1 purus. Curabitur sit amet est id sem auctor dignissim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum quam orci, @loc aliquet @dpt vel faucibus eget, aliquam quis orci.</p>
  <p>Nullam diam magna, egestas ac metus non, dignissim lobortis purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. In nec massa eget mi vestibulum @ville3 varius volutpat a nisl. Nulla enim magna, fringilla eu erat nec, ullamcorper pellentesque dui. Etiam consectetur diam lectus, et finibus tellus feugiat quis. Pellentesque eu hendrerit dui. Nunc ut maximus mi, nec facilisis nisi. Etiam porta condimentum velit id @ville4 finibus. Aenean pretium condimentum orci vel tempor.</p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chip").hover(function(e) {
    // Mouse In
    var text = $(this).text().trim();
    $(".search").html($(".search").html().replace(text, "<span class='highlight'>"+text+"</span>"));
  }, function(e) {
    // Mouse Out
    $.each($(".search p"), function(index, element) {
      $(element).html($(element).text());
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vf252sa/) to play around with.

> **NOTE:**
>
> My solution only highlights the first instance of the tag. If you need to highlight multiple tags at once you'll need to use RegEx - something similar to @BrentBoden's solution.
>
> More info on that here: [jQuery - replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574980/jquery-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you so much uom-pgregorio, i got it, thanks to both of you. Your code and fiddle help me so much, i've understood many things. Keep it up, and have a nice day.

Comment: @HackTom knowing that you **understand** the concept is a lot better than simply copying and pasting code so that's good. Glad you're learning. Happy coding!

Comment: i still have an issue, i can't highlight only the tag with the value of mouseenter... all spans are highlighted and all text is blurred. I would understand how to extract only the tag i want and blurred all others. Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yggcedg8/3/